# Extract string in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way in snowflake to do the followin

I want to provide input like below
'ab.cd@test.com,ef.gh@test.com,ij.kl.mn@test.com,op.qr@test.com'

output should be

ab.cd@test.com

That means, output would be starting from beginning before the first occurrence of "comma"

I am not sure if below code will work in all scenarios or there is a better way to do this in Snowflake

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING ('ab.cd@test.com,ef.gh@test.com,ij.kl.mn@test.com,op.qr@test.com', 1, 
CHARINDEX (',', 'ab.cd@test.com,ef.gh@test.com,ij.kl.mn@test.com,op.qr@test.com')-1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html) function:

```
SELECT 
SPLIT_PART('ab.cd@test.com,ef.gh@test.com,ij.kl.mn@test.com,op.qr@test.com', ',',1)
```

Output:

```
ab.cd@test.com
```

---

Alternatively [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE('ab.cd@test.com,ef.gh@test.com,ij.kl.mn@test.com,op.qr@test.com', ',')) s
WHERE s.Index = 1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use SPLIT_PART

Reference: SPLIT_PART
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html#split-part

```
select split_part('ab.cd@test.com,ef.gh@test.com,ij.kl.mn@test.com,op.qr@test.com' ,
',',1) from dual;
```